# How to pass model class data from one page another in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I won't have any connection for both the pages and here I need to save the model class globally and to use anywhere in all pages till app was in use and after it may can clear the data having in array but I can able to access anywhere in all pages in app and I tried using to save in `UserDefaults` it crashed. Can anyone help me how to implement this?

```
var sortModel = [Sort]()

for (_, value) in sortJson as! [String: Any] { 
    self.sortModel.append(Sort.init(dict: value as! [String : Any]))
}
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.sortModel, forKey: "sorts")
```

Comment: " I tried using to save in userdefaults it got crashed" Any error message? There is no `UserDefaults` line of code showed. In order to save `Sort` which is a Custom object into UserDefaults, you need to make it compliant with `NSCopy`, or since it seem you use JSON, Sort needs to be compliant with `Codable` and `Decodable` and you can save JSON in `UserDefaults` instead.

Comment: please provide the code. and do you need to persist data when app is relaunched?

Comment: Its better to keep it at application level, if you dont want it to persist once app is closed.

Comment: this is the error `Attempt to insert non-property list object` and user defaults code added as shown above then how to make `NSCopy` and to save it in user defaults @Larme

Comment: yes I need as u told @hkg328

Comment: Sorry, I meant `NSCoding` compliant, not `NSCopy`. Just do a quick search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your `Sort` struct to conform to `Codable` like:

```
struct Sort: Codable {
    //...
}
```

then you can quickly get away with:

```
//Encode Sort to json data
if let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(sortModel) {
    print("To Save:", jsonData)

    //Save as data
    UserDefaults.standard.set(jsonData,
                              forKey: "sorts")
}

//Read data for "sorts" key and decode to array of "Sort" structs
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "sorts"),
    let sorts = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Sort].self,
                                          from: data) {
    print("Retrieved:", sorts)
}
```

---

Basically, we make a `json` out of the `array` and save it as a `data` object.
We then can get it back as `data` and recreate the sort `struct` `array`.

NOTE: This may not work if the `struct` has nested within itself some types that prevent it from getting encoded as a `json`.

In this case, read:

- http://swiftandpainless.com/nscoding-and-swift-structs